# Problems with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Not sure if this is the right forum but, I am having problems plotting the following equation under gnuplot:

```
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:1]
(22/23)**x
```

All I get is a straight line from the fifth tick of the y-axis (i.e. y=1) to well before the first tick of the x-axis.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:1]
set parametric
plot t,(22.0/23.0)**t
```

Gnuplot will default to integers if you don't add a decimal point, and apparently can't raise integers to a power.